# Rebase pulled branch which has not been merged by repo owner

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase, pull-request

I have forked a projekt on Github. I have set up my local version of my fork to update from the original repo by [adding it as upstream](https://gist.github.com/CristinaSolana/1885435).

Now i created a feature branch, made changes and pulled to the origin repo. As the changes are huge, the pull has not (yet) been accepted by the repo owner.

Meanwhile i updated my master branch from the original repo´s master doing `git pull upstream master` a few times, so my feature branch is out of sync with the master branch.

I need them to be synced, because i need to generate documents from both branches and compare them.

What i know (im not a git pro) is that i would first locally commit my stashed changes in my feature branch and then, also locally, rebase my branch against the master (or how this is called in git lingua).

But i read that rebasing will create chaos in other peoples repos.

So how do i do this? Should i close my PR, do the rebasing on a new branch and pull that again? I would like if i could prevent this, because i dont want to pollute the original repo.

Comment: I don't completely follow your problem, but note that you may update a GitHub pull request any number of times by just updating the source branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you mean appending commits, yes, i know this and also did it a few times. But i wonder if that will also work if i rebase my pulled branch. Articles like [this one](https://medium.com/@fredrikmorken/why-you-should-stop-using-git-rebase-5552bee4fed1) suggest it is dangerous.

Comment: The thing is, when you rebase your branch you are _rewriting_ the history of the branch by changing the base.  Yes, it can be dangerous to do this to a published branch, and so maybe you should find another way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many git workflows, you can distinguish between feature branches and "stable" branches.

Take this example *(arbitrary workflow, could be different than yours, but just to make the point about stable/feature branches)* and consider its history :

```
     -----------------D <<< feature-bar
    /                  \
---A------------E-------H---J <<< master
    \          / \         /
     B--------C   F---G---I <<< feature-foo
```

`master` is a stable branch, it's permanent and reflects the current state of the application. In some workflows, you have more stable branches, one for staging, one for development, one for stable production state, and so on.

Feature branches, in the other hand, are volatile and disposable. Each one is created for a specific need (typically, a bug fix, a new feature), and is deleted when it's finally merged into its stable destination. (In the schema above, `feature-bar` and `feature-foo`, but we can also guess that there was a branch pointing to `C` at some point, which has been deleted after the `E` merge.)

When a developer works alone on their feature branch, if it's not yet merged, whatever they do on their branch stays on it and *that* part of history can be changed, by a rebase or any other operation, without ill effects on anyone else.

Of course, rebasing a stable branch would be a big no-no in most cases, because all the other developers share this part of the repo history and would have to resolve potentially nasty conflicts.

I used merges here in my schema and explanation, but a workflow using rebase would also make the same distinction between stable/feature branches.

---

**If you work alone on a feature branch**, then create a PR, and then realize you have to rebase it, no trouble, the PR will update itself after you've pushed the new history of the branch, and nothing will be messed in the destination branch's history.

**What can be a lot more problematic is to rebase stable branches**, shared with others, because it would cause conflicting histories, which, yes, can be nasty to resolve.

The article you linked is very interesting, I agree with the main point, however beware that it can be misleading when you discover git and try to use it efficiently. These are rather advanced considerations, which could be inducing "[cargo-cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)" practices if followed without a clear understanding. Rebase is a useful tool, don't throw it away.

Comment: Could you clarify the difference between a stable branch and the feature branch i was talking about? Does this mean that if others have forked my repo, in order to play around with my PR, it will break their setup when i rebase? If you do that, i will add an extra upvote.

Comment: Or do you just speak of the problem that a bugfix introduced after the branching may be accidently overwritten during the rebase?

Comment: You're right, I've been too concise here, I'll edit to elaborate a bit in a moment.

Comment: Thank you for defining this difference between_stable_ vs._feature_. One last question: If someone has forked my repo, in order to play around with my feature branch, am i correct that he will have to fork it again in order to play around with my branch after i rebased it?

Comment: I am asking because i want to inform those people what to do in this case.

Comment: @Nils If someone clones your repo with its feature branches, and then you rebase one of these, yes their history will conflict with yours. But if they're just inspecting and fiddling around, they'll be able to either delete the branch and recreate it anew from yours or even reclone the whole repo, it's not like they would have commits on their own on it. Problems would arise only IF they locally commit things on top of the branches you rebased then need to share them back to you.